# Split a graph before actually creating it

Tags: algorithms, graphs, max-cut

Consider a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ of vertex set $V = \{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ and weighted edge set $E = \{\langle v_i, v_j, w(i,j)\rangle \mid i, j \in 1, ..., n\}$, where $w$ is the function that assign the weight of a certain edge. This function $w$ is symmetric.

Suppose I want to partition the graph into multiple components $G_1, ..., G_k$:

- each component $G_i = (V_i, E_i)$ is such that $V_i \subseteq V$ and $E_i = \{ \langle v_i, v_j, w(i,j) \rangle \mid v_i, v_j \in V_i \} \subseteq E$;
- it holds that $\forall i, j \in 1, ..., k \quad V_i \cap V_j = \varnothing$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k V_i = V$;
- the set of edges lost by performing the partition is denoted with $E_\text{lost} = E \setminus (E_1 \cup ... \cup E_k)$ and the sum of lost weights is denoted with $w_\text{lost} = \sum\limits_{\langle v_i,v_j,w_{ij}\rangle \in E_\text{lost}} w_{ij}$

Do exist in the literature heuristics to solve this weighted graph partition problem, running in *linear* or *quasi-linear* time in $n$ (*), that minimize $w_\text{lost}$:

1. supposing $w$ is a metric, and
2. supposing $w$ is not a metric, and no further hypothesis holds except for the symmetry?

(*) solutions having quadratic complexity are not accepted

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis on the function $w$? If not, I am afraid that you cannot do better that a random selection of edges…

Comment: @Nathaniel Thank you for the comment! The function is symmetric but it's not necessarily a metric, actually. However, if some solution exists that works supposing $w$ is a metric, it might be worth showing it, so I've edited the question

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  I don't know what you mean by creating a graph; does that mean my algorithm can assign any weights it wants to each of the edges?  That seems hard to believe.  Do you mean the graph is provided as input?  It sounds like you want to output a partition of the graph into multiple components.  What is the objective function you are trying to minimize?  Is it the sum of weights of edges that cross between two different components? It would help if you can articulate the problem clearly.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your comment! Question fixed. Is this clearer?

Comment: Much clearer, thank you.  How is $w$ specified?  Are we given an oracle for $w$, i.e., a subroutine we can call with any $i,j$ to obtain the value of $w(i,j)$?

Comment: Is $k$ an input?  Or can the algorithm pick any $k$ it wants?  If $k$ is unrestricted, then the optimal solution is $k=1$.  If $k$ is an input, is it OK for the algorithm to have running time $O(kn)$?

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your answer. Actually, $w$ is an oracle. $k$ is indeed an input, it holds that $k = n/\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some constant (can be $\alpha \approx 100$). It's ok to have a running time of $O(kn)$. I'll keep the question open for a little time if you want to add further considerations.

Comment: @incud I am just curious why your target running time is entirely dependent on the number of vertices and number of components? As noted in the answer and comments, with that limitation, you may not be able to inspect all edges and might lead to large $w_{lost}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't solve this in subquadratic time with any guarantees at all; there is a simple adversary argument.  Consider any linear- or quasi-linear-time algorithm, and suppose it outputs the partition $G_1,\dots,G_k$.  For any non-trivial* partition, the number of lost edges is more than linear/quasi-linear, so there must exist some lost edge whose weight was not examined by the algorithm; call this edge $e$.  It follows that this algorithm will produce the same output regardless of whether the weight on edge $e$ is $0$ or $10^9$ (or some other huge value).  As a result, the value of $w_\text{lost}$ can be arbitrarily high.

So, it follows that for any algorithm that runs in linear time or quasi-linear-time, there exists some input where the partition it suggests is horrible.

If you don't care about guarantees, then you can do anything you want.  If you want a very simple heuristic, here is one.  Randomly sample linearly (or quasi-linearly) many edges, calculate their edge weights, and compute the $k-1$ lowest-weight edges.  For each those $k-1$ edges, arbitrarily pick one endpoint, and put it in a group of its own (containing only that one vertex and no other vertices).  Finally, put the remaining $n-k+1$ vertices into the final group.

If the algorithm can choose $k$, then the optimal solution is to set $k=1$ and put all vertices into a single group.

- = for an appropriate definition of "non-trivial"